# What does the notation $\chi_{(V\ge1)}$ mean in probability / statistics?

Tags: probability, notation

I reading Benjamini and Hochberg's paper on [controlling the FDR](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~doerge/BIOINFORM.D/FALL06/Benjamini%20and%20Y%20FDR.pdf), and I came across this notation "$\chi_{(V\ge1)}$" in section 2.1 paragraph (b), and I'm guessing from context that:
$$
\chi_{(V\ge1)}  = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & V\ge1\\ 
0 & Otherwise
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Can anyone confirm that this is correct or provide a correction, and also give the name of this construct/notation?

Comment: It is good practice to give references for papers you allude to, but I think you are right and that this is what often known as a characteristic function. (Think of $\chi$ being chi.) As explained in e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicFunction.html that term has another, usually more important, meaning in probability and statistics.

Comment: Thanks!  I added a link to the paper, and I'm sure it's the Characteristic function that they're using.

Comment: For more about indicator functions, please [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=indicator%20function). Note that this is only rarely (albeit) correctly referred to as a "characteristic function" because that term also has a completely different meaning which often occurs in similar contexts: it is a version of the Fourier transform of a probability measure.